# How to create page dynamically for every WooCommerce order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

Guys I'm trying to create a page for every WooCommerce order specifically. So user makes an order, I generate an ID for that order (the id will form the URL of the page)and whenever someone goes onto that url (mywebsite.com/generated_order_id) he can see info that is specific for the order.

So this would be the user story -> I confirm the order -> I get the URL of the page(That page is created dynamically, at the moment when I finished my order).

I'm not asking for the solution, just for the concepts, tools and a way I should look up to get to the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: WooCommerce already does that. How does the order-received page not do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to set access permission for page? Like only for that user.

Every time and order is generated, it's save to the database as a POST so you can get the id from there. Even that, WooCommerce generates an order page after the checkout process. The URL is something like:

**yourblog.com/checkout/order-received/{POST_ID}/?key={WC_ORDER_KEY}**

So You could use this page and edit the template from your theme.

Hope it helps!